# How do you set up a bare workflow react native project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm new in the field and when while reading the documentation it says that the difference between bare and managed workflow is the expo-cl command to initialize the project with.
But when I open the documentation the first thing it says to do it says expo-cli init (https://docs.expo.io/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/), which doesn't make sense?

what's the actual difference between the two in terms of creating a project and working with it?

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `expo init YourProject`, it will ask if you want to create a managed workflow or bare workflow project. For beginner, I suggest doing the managed workflow since it does a lot of background stuff for you.

The big difference is that in the managed workflow, everything goes through expo, even the build process. Which might not be a good idea if you are developing an app for a company. They actually move your code to their server and build it there.

You can also eject your project later on from a managed workflow. one thing to note is that some of the expo packages might not work after, and you will need to switch to a package that's compatible with the bare workflow.